# Insert into record results in 0 for last ID

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, when I run my SQL query, it returns 0 for the Last ID. My Insert Query does not work, but yet it gives me no errors when run. I check the database, and nothing new was inserted or added. The weird thing is, this query actually works on another page and I copied it over here, word for word, yet it does not work or insert. I'm stumped on this one. I can't figure out why when I run this query it does not do the insert.

```
require 'database.php';

$ingredient = (string)$_POST['ingredient'];
$meal = (string)$_POST['meal'];

if(isset($ingredient) && ($meal)){
    $ingr_exploded = explode(" @", $ingredient);
    $ingr = $ingr_exploded[0];
    $store = $ingr_exploded[1];

// copy ingredients columns into meal_ingredients table.
$sql = "INSERT INTO meal_ingredients (ingredients_id_fk, quanity, package, cost, store)
        SELECT ingredient_id, quanity, package, cost, store
        FROM ingredients
        WHERE item='$ingr' AND store='$store'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {$last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "Last ID = $last_id</br>";}    
    else {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>"  . $conn->error;}

// insert meal_name & ingredient_name into table.
$sql2 = "UPDATE meal_ingredients
        SET meal_name='$meal', item='$ingr'
        WHERE meal_ingredients_id=$last_id";

    if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {echo "Meal Name - Ingredient Set. </br>";}   
    else {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>"  . $conn->error;}

}
```

Comment: is your db connection included? e.g. (user, db , pass , host)

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to put that in the code display, but its connected.

Comment: are your post names correct?

Comment: add `echo($sql);` and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: It pretty much returns what is written. 
INSERT INTO meal_ingredients (ingredients_id_fk, quanity, package, cost, store) 
SELECT ingredient_id, quanity, package, cost, store 
FROM ingredients WHERE item='Ketchup' AND store=' S-Mart'

Comment: What happens if you run the query directly against the db? There seems to be an extra space there `' S-Mart`

Comment: Thank you SearchAndResQ, I fixed it! Basically looking at my own comment, I noticed that it rendered a space on the store name, thus it wasn't finding the store in the database because of that space. I updated my explode code to include the space, and now it works! Thank you!!

Comment: See about prepared statements in PDO